# orders in XmlHttpRequest's readyState change and onreadystatechange event handler execution?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-states

I have a question on temporal behavior regarding XmlHttpRequest objects.

Is it guarantee that a readyState value update and 
the corresponding onreadystatechange event handler 
invocation are executed consecutively ?

I checked out the JavaScript specification on W3C
(http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405),
however the temporal behavior of readyState is not 
clearly specified to answer the question.

I ran a small example code to check this issue, and found that 
at least in Firefox, no other event handler can be scheduled between 
the readyState update and the onreadystatechange event handler executions.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided a link to a working example that demonstrates what you're trying to do. (e.g. at http://jsfiddle.net/)